# Visualforce page for email and pdf print

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am trying to create the ability to print or email a salesforce page layout without the SF headers and side panel.  When I create the visualforce component it looks fine for the email but the pdf does not space the output fields properly.  Admittedly I am not very familiar with custom visualforce and I am following a model from a previous implementation. Below is the main vf page, the pdf page, and the component.  Is it possible to do this with one component or do I need to have two?  It would be great to have it look just like the page layout in SF.  I have a feeling it is some of the code in the pdf vf page, but to be honest I don't totally understand all the options used by the previous developer.

Main vf:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" tabStyle="Account" 
       standardController="Affiliate_Consulting_Engagement__c"
       extensions="pdfExtension"
       applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" >

<!-- generic markup for pdfExtension is in a form by itself... -->
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="text-align:left;">
      <apex:commandLink action="{!transferTopage }" value="Save PDF" styleClass="btn" id="btnPdf">
          <apex:param name="TransferPage"
                      assignTo="{!TransferPage}"
                      value="Affiliate_Engagement_Pdf" />
      </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="text-align:left;">
      <apex:outputLabel for="recipientEmail" value="Send To"/> 
      <apex:inputText value="{!recipientEmail }" size="40"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="text-align:left;">
      <apex:outputLabel for="subjectEmail" value="Email Subject (Optional)"/> 
      <apex:inputText value="{!subjectEmail }" size="40" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="text-align:left;">
      <apex:outputLabel for="bodyEmail" value="Email Text (Optional)" /> 
      <apex:inputTextarea value="{!bodyEmail}" rows="6" cols="20" richText="true" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="text-align:left;">
      <apex:commandLink action="{!emailPdf }" value="Email PDF" styleClass="btn" id="btnEmail">
          <apex:param name="TransferPage"
                      assignTo="{!TransferPage}"
                      value="Affiliate_Engagement_Pdf" />
      </apex:commandLink>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>   
</apex:form>

<c:AffEngComponent Engage="{!Affiliate_Consulting_Engagement__c }" RenderPDF="false" />    
</apex:page>
```

PDF page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" tabStyle="Account" 
       standardController="Affiliate_Consulting_Engagement__c"
       contentType="application/pdf" renderAs="PDF"
       applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" >

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
            @page { size:landscape; margin:4px }
            body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'}
            label { font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding-left:4px; padding-top:2px}
            .newpage { page-break-after:always}
            .header { font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding-left:6px; padding-top:2px}
            .header2 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding-left:6px; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:16px}
            .rosterheader { font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; padding-left:6px; padding-top:8px}
            .field { font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px; padding-left:6px; padding-top:6px}
            .hiddenfield { visibility: hidden}
            .blankline { visibility: hidden; font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px; padding-top:12px}
    </style>
</head>

<c:AffEngComponent Engage="{!Affiliate_Consulting_Engagement__c }" RenderPDF="true" />

</apex:page>
```

Snippet from component - still in development. Need to confirm before adding all the fields.

```
<apex:component controller="AffEngController">

<apex:attribute name="Engage" 
                type="Affiliate_Consulting_Engagement__c" 
                description="Affiliate Consulting Engagement"
                required="true"
                assignTo="{!AffEngage}"/>


<apex:attribute name="RenderPDF" 
                type="Boolean" 
                description="Render as PDF"
                required="true"
                assignTo="{!onlyIfPDF}"/>

<apex:form >                    

<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Oriel STAT A MATRIX" columns="1" >
        <apex:outputText styleClass="header1" label="" value="Consulting Engagement Details for {!Engage.Account_Name__c} - Details as of {!TODAY()}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Affiliate Consulting Engagement Detail" columns="2" >
        <apex:outputField value="{!Engage.Name}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Engage.User__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Engage.Engagement_Code__c}"/>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:component>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the email and the page and show us what the spacing issue is?

Comment: I'd avoid using the `<apex:component>`. See [Component Behavior when rendered as PDF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_component_behavior.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I am trying to create a pdf that closely resembles the actual page layout including two related lists.  Do you have or know where I can find a sample of the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try monkeying with the CSS for print using `display:none` for elements you want to hide.

```
@page print{
.header{display:none;}   
.header2{display:none;}
//etc for footer, side panel or whatever else you've got
}
```

Worked for me but then again I'm lazy.